# Firebase removed object comes back again using iOS SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, firebase

For example like below:

```
{
  "main": {
    "products": {
      "product-02": 0,
      "product-01": 0
    }
  }
}
```

I already add a FEventTypeValue to the products path.

```
NSString *path = @"/main/products";
Firebase *ref = [self.firebase childByAppendingPath:path];
[ref observeEventType:FEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FDataSnapshot *snapshot) {

}];
```

And there is a button action to delete specific productID:

```
NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"/main/products/%@", productID];
[[self.firebase childByAppendingPath:path] removeValueWithCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, Firebase *ref) {

}];
```

The deletion succeed. But as I am watching the changes in the Firebase App Dashboard, the productID object is deleted, but then it comes back again. What am I doing wrong? It seems like the `observeEventType:FEventTypeValue` is undo the deletion part.

Comment: just a guess, there might be some other function in your code who is listening to /main/products/ and pushes the data back when FEventTypeValue is called

Comment: @Joshua I am pretty sure there is no such code.